# Java Swing unable to remove a component

Tags: java, swing, inner-classes

I am trying to build a quiz game that rerender itself after user click on the button with answer.

I have added an action listener to 4 buttons. When the button is clicked, it is suppose to reach the outer class which extend JFrame and remove the QuestionPanel that extends the JPanel. And then create a new QuestionPanel and add it back to the frame.

The hierarchy in goes like this :
MainFrame (JFrame) -> QuestionPanel (JPanel) -> optionPanel (JPanel) -> button (JButton)

MainFrame(outer class)
-> QuestionPanel (inner class)
-> OptionPanel (inner class)

But it just freeze during execution
[image]

```
button.addActionListener(e->{
      boolean result = false;
      JButton target = (JButton) e.getSource();
      result = MainFrame.this.questions[currentQuestion].checkAnswer(target.getText());
      System.out.println(questions.length);
      if(currentQuestion != (questions.length - 1)){
            MainFrame.this.remove(qPanel);
            //qPanel is the instance of QuestionPanel
            currentQuestion++;
            qPanel = new QuestionPanel(questions[currentQuestion]);
            MainFrame.this.add(qPanel);
     }
});
```

Comment: I assume that your _question panel_ contains a `JLabel` or a `JTextComponent` that displays the question. Why not just change the text of the question? Look for method `setText()`.

Comment: *it is suppose to reach the outer class which extend JFrame and remove the QuestionPanel that extends the JPanel* Maybe it would be better to create the QuestionPanel one time and update the text of the JLabel and JButtons.

Comment: Or use a CardLayout so you can change the visible view quickly.

Comment: Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like many pointed out, you would be better off changing the text inside a component like a Label rather than removing a Jpanel and replacing it. There is simply no need for that, especially just to display text to a user.